# Prevent reopening workbook by double clicking if already open

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I want to prevent opening of the workbook which is already opened.
My Workbook contains VBA userform.

Event of reopening the workbook is triggered by the double clicking on the workbook icon stored at particular location and the same file was previously open and running VBA userform.

I have tried following code but it is not helping me to prevent reopening.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If ThisWorkbook.IsInplace = True Then
        MsgBox "Workbook Already Open"
        ThisWorkbook.Close (False)
    Else
        MsgBox "Single Instance Open"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Expected Output**:
When I double click on excel file while file is already open then it should do nothing ideally( or it can override the workbook)

**Actual Output**:
When I double click on excel file while file is already open then it will pop up dialog box "File is already open and reopening of file will discard the changes" with yes , no and cancel option.

Comment: _" double clicking on the workbook icon stored at particular location"_: do you mean you have some `GetOpenFilename()` method running or similar?

Answer (score 2):

> Actual Output: When I double click on excel file while file is already open then it will pop up dialog box "File is already open and reopening of file will discard the changes" with yes , no and cancel option.

This is the default behaviour and AFAIK it cannot be changed. And it **shouldn't** as a well. At least this way you **know** that the workbook is already open and you have an option to **click** on `No`. Inspite the alert if you still click on `Yes` then you can't blame the system for it. Can you? ;)

Imagine if you did manage to get what you want then if the user is not aware of what you have done, will assume that either the mouse is not working or there is something wrong with the Excel Application. Why do you want to make things complicated???

Comment: I am working on Quotation Generation tool, so whenever user double click to open workbook, Userform will be invoke, and I have used Application.Visible = False so that user can not see the excel Sheets, so only thing accessible by user will be Form and not excel sheets. but if user is not aware that the workbook is already open and if user double clicks on the workbook to open it again then with "file already open" dialog box will open and because of this dialog box somehow excel sheets will be visible to user.

Comment: You are missing the point... "You will get an alert". You have a choice of clicking "No"

Comment: If user is not aware that the workbook is open and user double clicks the workbook to open it, it will make sheets to appear along with form, while only thing I want to keep visible is form and not worksheets, "file already open" dialog box prompting is not an actual problem, but that makes worksheets visible is something I do not want. so any way to prevent worksheets to appear on desktop with this dialog box.